# keras: extract feature names from a saved model

Tags: keras

I have a large number of features. I train several keras models by varying the number of features to see the impact of these features on model accuracy. In the end, when I load these models, I no longer know on which features the model was trained on so when I do the predictions, I get the error like:

`Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have shape (29,) but got array with shape (47,)`

Is there a way to know what are the exact feature names on which the model was trained?
I use `keras.models.load_model` to load the model and `keras.models.sequence.save(path)` to save the model.